# Magento 2: Custom module installed but not working

Tags: magento2, module

Have created a module and it works fine on staging and locally but not working on live. The module is installed correctly and enabled. The live config.php and the staging config.php are the same. I used the live db on staging and it is working fine which means is not a db problem.

Also cleared the cache. In my custom module I have a before plugin for `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success execute()` and overwritten `Iways\PayPalPlus\Controller\Order\Create.php.`

Looks like the code is never executed. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: I guess your module is not deployt correctly. did you call setup:di:compile?
I stage also running in production mode? or in devloper

Comment: @PhilippSander Jenskis probably executes setup:di:compile

Comment: Which application mode are you running in local / staging environments? Production? Developer? Try running production mode (assuming live site is running in production mode) in local / staging & check what happens

Comment: Any error? server error log?

Comment: "looks like" and "probably" are not helping. you need facts.

Answer (score 0):

First check how many server for production. If more than one, then you need to commit **config.php** file too. After that clear cache.

Comment: The config.php is commited. I checked the module is there and enabled